# Can't proceed with main method after do while loop

Tags: java, while-loop, program-entry-point, do-while

I am new to Java and working on simple task - TicTacToe console game. Today I've faced a problem that I can't proceed with the main method after do `while` loop. The project has two classes - `Main` and `Field`. Field is responsive for all game field updates. I'm calling `Field` methods in do while loop of the main method but when the result is on the loop has to be finished and the main method has to go on(it should ask if the user wants to play again). Unfortunately the programm stops after do `while` loop.

Here is my code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    private static char playerSym, compSym;
    private static int Sym;
    public static int playerChoice;
    public static boolean result;

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        Field field = new Field();

        // start of the game
        System.out.println("Let`s play");
        System.out.println("Choose your symbol please");
        System.out.println("0='O', 1='X'");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        Sym = sc.nextInt();

        while (Sym != 0 & Sym != 1) {
            System.out
                    .println("The symbol you entered is incorrect, please repeat");
            System.out.println("0='O', 1='X'");
            Sym = sc.nextInt();
        }

        // setting player character
        if (Sym == 1) {
            playerSym = 'X';
            compSym = 'O';
        } else if (Sym == 0) {
            playerSym = 'O';
            compSym = 'Х';
        }

        System.out.println("There is a game field");
        System.out.println("Please choose the cell number you`d like to fill with  " + playerSym);
        field.firstShowFields();

        do {
            playerChoice = (Integer) sc.nextInt();
            field.updateFields(playerChoice, playerSym);
            field.showFields(field.fields);
        } while (result==false);

        System.out.println("Want to play once more? Y-Yes, N-No");
        char answer = (char) System.in.read();

        switch (answer) {
            case 'Y':
                System.out.println("Restarting the game");
                break;
            case 'N':
                System.out.println("Thank you! Bye-Bye!");
                break;
            default:
                break;  
        }   
    }
}

public class Field {
    public static final int FIELD_SIZE = 3;
    // private static final char DEFAULT_CHAR=' ';

    public char[][] fields;
    public boolean result = true;
    public char playerSym;

    public Field() {
        fields = new char[FIELD_SIZE][FIELD_SIZE];
    }

    public void firstShowFields() {
        int cellValue = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < FIELD_SIZE; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < FIELD_SIZE; j++) {
                System.out.print("[" + cellValue + "]");
                cellValue++;
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public char[][] updateFields(int choice, char sym) {
        playerSym = sym;
        int cellValue = 1;
        int playerChoice = choice;

        do {
            for (int i = 0; i < FIELD_SIZE; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < FIELD_SIZE; j++) {

                    if (playerChoice == cellValue) {
                        fields[i][j] = (char) playerSym;
                    } else if (fields[i][j] == (char) playerSym) {
                        fields[i][j] = (char) playerSym;
                    } else {
                        fields[i][j] = (char) ('0' + cellValue);
                    }

                    cellValue++;
                }

            }

            this.checkWin(fields, playerSym);
            return fields;

        } while (this.checkWin(fields, playerSym) == false);
    }

    public void showFields(char[][] fields) {
        this.fields = fields;
        for (int i = 0; i < FIELD_SIZE; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < FIELD_SIZE; j++) {
                System.out.print("[" + fields[i][j] + "]");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public boolean checkWin(char[][] field, char playerSym) {
        char[][] checkField = field;
        this.playerSym = playerSym;

        // checkline
        if (((checkField[0][0] == checkField[0][1]) && (checkField[0][1] == checkField[0][2]))
                || ((checkField[1][0] == checkField[1][1]) && (checkField[1][1] == checkField[1][2]))
                || ((checkField[2][0] == checkField[2][1]) && (checkField[2][1] == checkField[2][2]))) {

            System.out.println("The game is over. The winner is player " + playerSym);
            return  true;
        } 
        // checkraw
        else if (((checkField[0][0] == checkField[1][0]) && (checkField[1][0] == checkField[2][0]))
                || ((checkField[0][1] == checkField[1][1]) && (checkField[1][1] == checkField[2][1]))
                || ((checkField[0][2] == checkField[1][2]) && (checkField[1][2] == checkField[2][2]))) {
            System.out.println("The game is over. The winner is player " + playerSym);
            return result = true;

        } // checkdiagonal
        else if (((checkField[0][0] == checkField[1][1]) && (checkField[1][1] == checkField[2][2]))
                || ((checkField[0][2] == checkField[1][1]) && (checkField[1][1] == checkField[2][0]))) {
            System.out.println("The game is over. The winner is player " + playerSym);
            return result = true;
        }
            return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: There are many while loops. Which one you mean?

Answer (score 2):

Here is an infinite loop:

```
do {
        playerChoice = (Integer) sc.nextInt();
        field.updateFields(playerChoice, playerSym);
        field.showFields(field.fields);
    } while (result==false);
```

`result` is never updated so the `while (result==false);` will never fail as long as it was true the first time. You may try modifying it like below:

```
do {
        playerChoice = (Integer) sc.nextInt();
        field.updateFields(playerChoice, playerSym);
        field.showFields(field.fields);
        result = field.checkWin(field.fields, playerSym);
    } while (result==false);
```

Also, it is not a good practice to pass fields that are already attached to the instance to instance methods. You can remove the parameter `char[][] field` from the checkWin method and simply have it operate on the instance variable `fields`. But that's not the cause of your loop issue.

Comment: Thank you very much! It`s working now of course. Can I thank you  someway here on stackoverflow?

Comment: I don't know of any way other than accepting the answer and maybe giving it an upvote, if you like. In any case, glad it's working!

Answer (score 0):

As user506 points out the only reason why it won't progress past the loop is because the boolean `result` is never set to `true`.

Why do you have 2 classes to separate the main method?

Comment: cw1201, I don`t know, that`s how I designed(I wrote that I`m new to java). What is the better way?